How to get X coordinate of crane bridge to put it in a variable in Anylogic
I use overhead crane in my model and I need to know position of its bridge (or hook - even better) during simulation - it is used in variable.
I tried func getBridgePosition(), but I dont understand how to get X coordinate from it. It has type "position" and cannot be read as any type of data. Also I tried craneBridge.getX() inside of my variable, but it shows only home position of bridge or is not updating during simulation. Function update() doesn't work with it as well.

PS: Only use the "anylogic" tag, it suffices on SOF

getBridgePosition() returns a Position.
In such cases, first read up on that in the help. Then, keep using code-complete to get what you need.
In your case, getBridgePosition().getX()
Same works for the hook but you need to specify the bridge: getHookPosition(OverheadCraneBridge bridge).getX()
